# What can I use to mask a string?

Tags: java

How can I hide parts of a user entry?

Im trying to, as part of a homework assignment, mask the first five digits of a social security number that the user enters. The instructon for the below class says: "The getSsn() method should return a masked version of the social security number that only reveals the last four numbers." This tells me I need to hide the first five. I know the substring and .replace methods could be useful, but Im not sure how to go about it, considering we haven't gone into strings in ultra detail yet. How can I achieve this with what Ive got so far? What do I need to change?

```
public class Employee extends Person {
    private String SSN;    
    private String x;    
    public Employee(String FirstName, String LastName, String SSN) {

    }    

    public String getSSN(String SSN) {
        String part1 = SSN.substring(0,3);
        String part2 = SSN.substring(4,5);
        String part3 = SSN.substring(6,9);
        SSN = SSN.replace(0,5,'x'); 

        return SSN; 
    }    

    public void setSSN(String SSN) {
        this.SSN = "SSN";
    }
}
```

As for errors, I know the .replace statement needs to come out.

Comment: Use substring and concatenation; e.g. `ssn = "xxxxx" + ssn.substring(5);`

Comment: check the length of the `SSN` string else a exception will be thrown if trying to do a substring with values that are not valid.  Then you can return `"xxxxx" + part3` As per Stephens comment above probably `part3` is not correct.

Comment: Part 3. Would I need to take it out, or reformat it?

Answer (score 2):

An approach would be replaceFirst()

```
String s = "123456789";
s = s.replaceFirst("^.{5}", "*****");
```

Also, I think your "setSSN" function is incorrect as you have coded it to always to as String "SSN" as opposed to the variable SSN, i.e. should be:

```
public void setSSN(String SSN) {
this.SSN = SSN;
}
```

Comment: How can I fix this?

Comment: sorry, fix what in particular?

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified. Fix my setSSN method. What about it was wrong?

Comment: Ah okies, your code this.SSN = "SSN"; will always set the SSN variable as "SSN" as opposed to what's in the variable SSN

Comment: So how can I change it to where it uses whats in the variable itself?

Comment: change "SSN" to SSN.